# Convergence of sum of functions translated by rationals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $(q_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $(a_k)$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers such that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k<\infty$. Let $f(x)=x^{-1/2} $  if $0<x\leq1$ and equal to $0$ else. Let $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kf(x-q_k)$. Prove that F converges to a finite vaule for almost every $x \in [0,1]$. However, if $a_k$ are positive, prove also that for any interval $I\subset[0,1]$, the restriction of $F$ to $I$ is unbounded. Give other conditions on the pair of sequences $(a_k)$ and $(q_k)$ which
suffice to ensure that the restriction of $F$ to any interval $I$ is unbounded?

My try on it: $$\int_{0}^{1} F(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\int_{0}^{1} f(x-q_k)dx \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-q_k)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k <\infty $$ And since it is integrable then $F(x)$ converges a.e. on $[0,1]$ Also for any $I$ I can always find a rational $q_k$ in $I$ and so I can make the denominator for $f(x-q_k)$ close to zero thus make $F(x)$ unbounded.

Is my approach correct? Also can anyone help me find conditions on the pair of sequences $(a_k)$ and $(q_k)$ which
suffice to ensure that the restriction of $F$ to any interval $I$ is unbounded?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The proof of unboundedness is flawed and actually $F$ can be bounded. Just use $a_k = 0$ for all $k$. Note that the integration estimate you use works as long as $q_k$ is bounded. The claim can be fixed by requiring $a_k > 0$ and not $a_k \ge 0$.

Comment: Yeah your right for the second part we have to assume that $a_k>0$. Fixed.

Comment: If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=\infty$, does this make $F(x)$ unbounded?

Comment: Not so sure. I'm thinking of a scenario where $a_k > 0$ won't make $F|_I$ unbounded. Something like $a_k = \exp(-k)$. This will converge to $0$ faster than an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ wich might make $F$ bounded _everywhere_...

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure of the following counter-example for part two:
Let $a_k = \exp(-k)$ and $q_k$ the usual enumeration of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. Note that $q_k \ge \frac c{k^3}$ because the denominator in the enumeration increases by $1$ only every triangular number, wich is $O(n^2)$. Finally note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k f(x-q_k) \color{red}\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k f(q_k) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty c \exp(-k) k^{\frac32} < \infty$$
The only gap is the $\color{red}\le$.

Comment: This $a_k,q_k$ pair will make the F bounded. What about one that will make it unbounded?